# What is the JSF equivalent of the Spring framework "model" object?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsf, jsf-2.2

In Spring you have to add attributes to the `model` object between view requests. Then those views use that model object to retrieve the attributes and display them. Is there an equivalent in JSF?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.google.com/search?q=JSF+beans

You should annotate your model class as `@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean`.
Managed (Backing) bean's parameter access happens through getters/setters.

And also `@SessionScoped`, `@RequestScoped`, etc define the scope of the bean.

Ex:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
class MyProfileBean{

    private String myName;

    //getters/setters
}
```

myprofile.xhtml

```
Name: <span> #{myProfileBean.myName} </span>
```